# Detect text from an image and get the rect of an keyword

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, apple-vision

I'm trying to get all the text found in an `UIImage` using `VisionKit` and get the location of a keyword (if it exists) in the image. So far I've got this:

```
    var detectedText = ""
    var textRecognitionRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: nil)
    let textRecognitionWorkQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "TextRecognitionQueue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)

    private func recognizeTextInImage(_ image: UIImage?) {
        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return }

        textRecognitionWorkQueue.async {
            let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
            do {
                try requestHandler.perform([self.textRecognitionRequest])
            } catch {
                // You should handle errors appropriately in your app.
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

And in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imgData = object.scannedImage ?? Data()
        recognizeTextInImage(UIImage(data: imgData, scale: 1.0))

        textRecognitionRequest.recognitionLevel = .accurate
        textRecognitionRequest.usesLanguageCorrection = true
        textRecognitionRequest.recognitionLanguages = ["en-US"]
        textRecognitionRequest.customWords = ["KEYWORD"]
        textRecognitionRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
            guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else { return }
            for observation in observations {
                guard let topCandidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first else { return }

                self.detectedText += topCandidate.string
                self.detectedText += " "

                if topCandidate.string == "KEYWORD" {
                    let boundingBox = observation.boundingBox
                    guard let imageData = object.scannedImage else { return }
                    let imgSize = UIImage(data: imageData)!.size
                    let rect = CGRect(x: boundingBox.minX * imgSize.width,
                                                   y: boundingBox.minY * imgSize.height,
                                                   width: boundingBox.width * imgSize.width,
                                                   height: boundingBox.height * imgSize.height)
                    print(rect)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the detection of the `boundingBox` really slows down the process of finding all the text in the image and it gets really inaccurate and the printing of the rect never gets called.

Is there a better way of doing this?